# If-else Time complexity

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm struggling with the problem about time-complexity of Python 3.
Recently I found that the difference of results between these two codes:
(The purpose of these codes is to check whether we can make an integer a to an integer b using some methods. You are only able to use two methods: 2x or 10x+1. If impossible, this code will return -1. I will attach some examples with an image.)

code A.

```
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    n=1
    while b!=a:
        n+=1
        if b%10==1:
            b=b//10
        elif b%2==0:
            b//=2
        else:
            n=-1
            break;
    print(n)
```

code B.

```
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    n=1
    while b!=a:
        n+=1
        c=b
        if b%10==1:
            b=int(b/10)
        elif b%2==0:
            b/=2
        if c==b:
            print(-1)
            break
    else:
    print(n)
```

When I applied some test cases to code A, I couldn't get the result value within the time I targeted (2 seconds). However, I checked that I can accomplish my purpose using code B.
Thus, I guessed that there exist some problems related to time-complexity, since I think that both codes (A and B) are following the same logic.
(Or maybe I'm missing some code error.)
I would like to get some advice with these problems. Thank you very much!

Reference: https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/16953

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xetRk.png)

Comment: In python whitespace is part of the syntax, so you should probably ensure that you carefully copy and paste the original indentation into your question.

Comment: We can't tell what either of these pieces of code do, because you've somehow managed to completely lose all indentation when pasting them here.  Without indentation, it's impossible to tell just what's inside a `while` loop or `if` statement, and what's outside.  The one thing that jumps out at me is that the first code has `n=-1` (which might actually need to be `n -= 1`), but there's nothing similar to that in the second version.

Comment: Thank you so much! Taking your advice, I made up for the deficiencies in the code description.

Comment: The difference between code B and code A is not only `if else` but also the usage of `/` instead of `//`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent. Code A can get into an infinite loop.

For instance, when the input is `2 11`, we get these iterations of the loop:

In the first iteration the `if` condition is true, and `b` is assigned 1.

In the second iteration the `if` condition is true, and `b` is assigned 0.

In the third iteration the `elif` condition is true, and `b` is assigned 0 (no change)

In the fourth iteration the exact same thing happens as in the previous iteration, and so you have an infinite loop.

The B-version of the code would detect this situation because with `if c==b:` it really checks whether `b` changed at all in the current iteration, and so avoids an infinite loop. In that case it outputs -1 and exits.

You could fix your version by changing your `elif` to:

```
elif b and b%2==0:
```